Launch Automator Workflow and pass parameter from Apple Script
I have:

an Automator workflow saved as an application "workflow.app"
an Apple Script saved as an application "script.app"
a PDF file residing on Desktop "test.pdf"

How do I launch workflow.app and pass test.pdf as the input for workflow from inside script.app?

tell application "workflow" to open "Macintosh HD:Users:user_name:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~CloudDocs:test.pdf"

Why not just have the workflow application open the file directly?

Because I need the script to choose and pass the file.

An Automator application can choose files or have files dropped onto it and run scripts without needing a separate application.
